# How do I find out what package is adding red boxes to my source code?

Tags: lsp-mode, flymake, enh-ruby-mode

I have this piece of ruby code:

```ruby
  def open(...)
    local_path.open(...)
  end
```

and the first two lines have red boxes around them and when I hover over either one it says "syntax error, unexpected ..., expecting ')'"

I have lsp-mode, projectile, etc.  Indeed, here is the complete list of minor modes in this buffer:

```
Enabled minor modes: Abbrev Async-Bytecomp-Package
Auto-Compile-On-Load Auto-Compile-On-Save Auto-Composition
Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Blink-Cursor Company Eldoc
Electric-Indent File-Name-Shadow Flymake Font-Lock Global-Company
Global-Eldoc Global-Font-Lock Global-Rbenv Helm
Helm-Minibuffer-History Inf-Ruby Leaf-Key-Override-Global Line-Number
Lsp Lsp-Completion Lsp-Diagnostics Lsp-Headerline-Breadcrumb
Lsp-Managed Lsp-Modeline-Code-Actions Lsp-Modeline-Diagnostics
Lsp-Modeline-Workspace-Status Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Projectile
Projectile-Rails Recentf Rspec Rspec-Verifiable Rubocop Shell-Dirtrack
Show-Paren Tab-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark
```

Someone is using the wrong version of Ruby but who?

Answer (score 4):

What I did is put the point on top of the error line and then did `M-: (face-at-point)` which gave `erm-syn-errline`.  I then went `grep`ing through the source and found that it was coming from enhanced ruby mode.

Looking in the source, I discovered that it parses the file using `enh-ruby-program`.  So I temporarily customized the variable and that got rid of the errors.

I would be interested in more direct methods of solving this problem.

Comment: +1. What you did is quite direct. Alternatively, to find the file defining that face, you can use command `describe-face`. That tells you the file that face is defined in.